# How can strings be concatenated?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

How to concatenate strings in python?

For example:

```
Section = 'C_type'
```

Concatenate it with `Sec_` to form the string:

```
Sec_C_type
```

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The easiest way would be

```
Section = 'Sec_' + Section
```

But for efficiency, see: https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

Comment: Actually it seems to have been optimized since the article you cite. From a quick test with timeit, I wasn't able to reproduce the results.

Comment: The OP asked for Python 2.4 but about version 2.7, Hatem Nassrat has tested (July 2013) [three concatenation techniques](http://leadsift.com/python-string-concatenation/) where `+` is faster when concatenating less than 15 strings but he recommends the other techniques: `join`and `%`. (this current comment is just to confirm the @tonfa's comment above). Cheers ;)

Comment: What happens if you want a multi line string concatenation?

Comment: @pyCthon: Huh? You can put a line break in a string using `\n` or you can do a line continuation in Python by putting a \ at the end of the line.

Answer (score 44):

you can also do this:

```
section = "C_type"
new_section = "Sec_%s" % section
```

This allows you not only append, but also insert wherever in the string:

```
section = "C_type"
new_section = "Sec_%s_blah" % section
```

Comment: This method also allows you to 'concat' an int to string, which isn't possible directly with `+` (requires wrapping the int in a `str()`)

Answer (score 29):

Just a comment, as someone may find it useful - you can concatenate more than one string in one go:

```
>>> a='rabbit'
>>> b='fox'
>>> print '%s and %s' %(a,b)
rabbit and fox
```

Answer (score 24):

More efficient ways of concatenating strings are:

**join():**

Very efficent, but a bit hard to read.

```
>>> Section = 'C_type'  
>>> new_str = ''.join(['Sec_', Section]) # inserting a list of strings 
>>> print new_str 
>>> 'Sec_C_type'
```

**String formatting:**

Easy to read and in most cases faster than '+' concatenating

```
>>> Section = 'C_type'
>>> print 'Sec_%s' % Section
>>> 'Sec_C_type'
```

Comment: Seems like join is the fastest and efficient too http://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

Answer (score 6):

Use `+` for string concatenation as:

```
section = 'C_type'
new_section = 'Sec_' + section
```

Answer (score 4):

To concatenate strings in python you use the "+" sign

ref: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-40.html

Answer (score 2):

For cases of appending to end of existing string:

```
string = "Sec_"
string += "C_type"
print(string)
```

results in

```
Sec_C_type
```