# Show first characters of a string and add "..." behind it

Tags: string, python-2.5

I actually want to know how i can actually only show the first characters of a string and show after the first characters a "...".

I already searched a bit and found:

```
I want to show only the first 10 characters:

character_name = "Ð¸Ð¼ Ù  frag /watch?v=Q-2tZ8ttE"
name = character_name[10:]
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that it could be also the case, that the name is less than 10 characters and there shouldnt be a "..." afterwards. Only for names which contain more than 10 Characters.
But how i can add afterwards a "..." after the 10 characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate strings in python 2.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711579/concatenate-strings-in-python-2-4)

Comment: totally unclear for me. What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
>>> def remove(s):
        if len(s) > 9:
            return character_name[:10] + '...'


>>> print remove('Ð¸Ð¼ Ù  frag /watch?v=Q-2tZ8ttE')
Ð¸Ð¼ Ù  fr...
>>> print remove('Ð¸Ð¼ Ù  fr')
Ð¸Ð¼ Ù  fr...
>>> print remove('Ð¸Ð¼ Ù  f')
None
```