# How to insert var content inside message body of sendmail function

Tags: python, sendmail

I have the next function:

```
hostname = os.uname()[1]

def sendmail(sender, receiver, content, user=None, password=None, hostname='localhost', port=25,ssl=False):
smt_server = 'localhost'
port = '25'
sender = 'jenkins@jenkins.com'
receiver = 'test@test.es'

content = "I need to show hostname here" , hostname , "Done."

msg = MIMEText(content)
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver
msg['Subject'] = 'Simple app script'

try:
   s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', port )
   s.sendmail('jenkins@jenkins.com', 'test@test.es', content)
   s.quit()
   print "Succesfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: fail to send email"
```

Actual result:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Expected result:

The body message of the mail have to be:

```
I need to show hostname here MyHostname Done.
```

I'm not sure if i'm using the rigth way, could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can strings be concatenated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711579/how-can-strings-be-concatenated)

Answer (score 1):

You can add strings:

```
content = "I need to show hostname here" + hostname + "Done."
```

Comment: Wow, so easy. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this to make content one string.

```
content = "I need to show hostname here " + hostname + " Done."
```

Comment: Wow, so easy. Thanks a lot!