# Adding a full stop '.' after every sentence line while using spacy NLP to perform summarisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I want to add a full stop after every line of sentence that I am getting from my cleaned text after performing text cleaning in order to perform summarisation using heapq or gensim. If I don't get a full stop, heapq or Gensim will not understand the different sentences and would take all the sentences as one. I am using the following code :

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
text = nlp(str1_clean_summary)

for sent in text.sents:
  print(sent.string.strip())
```

str1_clean_summary looks like this :

```
many price increase options 
still believe us need prove consistently 
aim please delay end displeasingich
responds wuickly
```

This gives me sentences in a different lines but I need to add a full stop after each sentence so they are treated separately.

Comment: `for sent in text.sents:
  print(sent.string.strip())` just prints the sentences without leading/trailing whitespace, do you mean you want to also add a dot to that output if missing?

Comment: It would help if you gave us examples of your input text (str1_clean_summary)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Yes I want to want add a full stop after every line of output I am getting after this code. I have shared the set of output above.

Comment: Why not do that then? `print(sent.string.strip() + '.')`. Or `print('{}.'.format(sent.string.strip()))`, `print(f'{sent.string.strip()}.')`

Comment: A duplicate of [How can strings be concatenated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711579/how-can-strings-be-concatenated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to fiddle with span indexing, I'd recommend you to add the final dot to each sentence before running spacy through them.

Ex.:

```
import en_core_web_sm
sents = "many price increase options\nstill believe us need prove consistently\naim please delay end displeasingich\nresponds wuickly\n"
sents = sents.replace('\n', '.\n')

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
text = nlp(sents)

for sent in text.sents:
  sentence = sent
  print(sentence)
```

Output:

> many price increase options.
>
> still believe us need prove consistently.
>
> aim please delay end displeasingich.
>
> responds wuickly.

Otherwise you'll have to work with token positioning (spans are token lists and due to spacy internal way to organize its vocabulary and other resources, the tokens in a span are "pointers" to a token dictionary. To add a new token, you'd have to move the tails of each span forward which is worse than just playing with a simple replace.)
Read more [here](https://spacy.io/api/span) and [here](https://spacy.io/api/token/).