# String is returned as a Tuple

Tags: python, string, function, return, tuples

I wrote a function in Python which returns should simple string based on 3 parameters, but it returns a tuple instead of a string.

```
def my_TAs(test_first_TA, test_second_TA, test_third_TA):

    return test_first_TA, test_second_TA, "and", test_third_TA, "are awesome!."

test_first_TA = "Joshua"

test_second_TA = "Jackie"

test_third_TA = "Marguerite"

print(my_TAs(test_first_TA, test_second_TA, test_third_TA))
```

Output:

```
('Joshua', 'Jackie', 'and', 'Marguerite', 'are awesome!')
```

Desired output:

```
"Joshua, Jackie, and Marguerite are awesome!".
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can strings be concatenated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711579/how-can-strings-be-concatenated)

Comment: The operator for concatenating strings is `+`, not `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that in python, if you use , to separate some values, it is interpreted as a tuple. So when you return, you are returning a tuple, not a string. You could either join the tuple, or use format strings like below.

```
return f'{test_first_TA}, {test_second_TA}, and {test_third_TA} are awesome!'
```

Comment: True, I have since updated my solution to explain why that is so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using join

```
def my_TAs(test_first_TA, test_second_TA, test_third_TA):
    return test_first_TA, test_second_TA, "and", test_third_TA, "are awesome!."

test_first_TA = "Joshua"
test_second_TA = "Jackie"
test_third_TA = "Marguerite"

print(' '.join(my_TAs(test_first_TA, test_second_TA, test_third_TA)))
```