# Running an executable in a loop that only processes first file

Tags: python

Pretty new to python.  I'm trying to run a loop to convert hgt files to sdf files using the following script:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for name in files:
        os.system("srtm2sdf-win.exe *.hgt")
```

But the script only deals with the very first file.  Here is the output:

```
Reading N10W110.hgt...
Writing 10x11x109x110.sdf... Done!
Reading N10W110.hgt...
Writing 10x11x109x110.sdf... Done!
Reading N10W110.hgt...
Writing 10x11x109x110.sdf... Done!
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `os.system("srtm2sdf-win.exe *.hgt")` is always the same command--did you mean to use `name`?

Comment: I was trying to figure how to use name.  Basically the files all end in hgt and the file conversion is executed by running the command srtm2sdf-win.exe <filename>

Comment: How about `os.system(f"srtm2sdf-win.exe {name}.hgt")` if you're on Python 3.6+?

Comment: Version 3.3.2, so did not work.  I can upgrade to 3.6 and try

Comment: Nah, just use `os.system("srtm2sdf-win.exe %s.hgt" % name)`. The question seems to reduce down to "how do I concatenate/interpolate strings in Python pre 3.6?".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can strings be concatenated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711579/how-can-strings-be-concatenated)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had to modify it slightly.  The code that worked is: `import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
  for name in files:
   if name.endswith(".hgt"):
    os.system("srtm2sdf-win.exe %s" % name)`

Comment: Nice to hear and good work--I forgot that `name` has the extension attached. Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).